# format csv data and write it to a text file for machine learning

Tags: python, csv

How do i arrange my data that i have changed from .csv to .txt file. I want to do this for my machine learning code.

```
import csv
csv_file = ('traindata.csv')
txt_file = ('traindata.txt')
with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        [ my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
    my_output_file.close()
```

This will give me an outcome that looks like this (see below) which is saved into the .txt file.

```
 x y z
0 -222.0 34.0 75.0
1 -222.0 34.0 75.0
2 -223.0 41.0 72.0
3 -223.0 41.0 72.0
4 -223.0 41.0 72.0
5 -231.0 36.0 78.0
6 -231.0 36.0 78.0
7 -231.0 36.0 78.0
```

However, I want it to look like this (see below). This is so that i can extract the data into my main code to use for Machine Learning.

```
X:-219, Y:5, Z:96
X:-219, Y:5, Z:96
X:-218, Y:5, Z:101
X:-218, Y:5, Z:101
X:-218, Y:5, Z:101
X:-215, Y:7, Z:99
```

This is because I want my main code to be able to extract the data from the .txt file

```
r = []
i = 0
e = glob.glob('traindata.txt')

for g in range(len(e)):
    if e[i>0]:

        file = open(e[i], 'r')
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        t1 = []
        z1 = []
        y1 = []
        x1 = []

        for line in lines:

            parts = line.split(", ")
            if len(parts) > 3:
                column1 = parts[3].split(':')
                column2 = column1[1]
                column3 = parts[2].split(':')
                column4 = column3[1]
                column5 = parts[1].split(':')
                column6 = column5[1]
                column7 = parts[0].split(':')
                column8 = column7[1]

                T = column2[0:len(column2)]
                Z = column4[0:len(column4)]
                Y = column6[0:len(column6)]
                X = column8[0:len(column8)]

               # pdb.set_trace()              
                T1 = float(T)
                t1.append(T1)                   
                X1 = float(X)
                x1.append(X1)                        
                Y1 = float(Y)
                y1.append(Y1)        
                Z1 = float(Z)
                z1.append(Z1)

    i += 1            
    m = x1+y1+z1
    r.append(m)

r = np.matrix(r)
```

csv file data: 
[image: Data Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row` gives you list of values, you can assign it to `X`, `Y` and `Z` before writing it to a file,

```
import csv
csv_file = ('traindata.csv')
txt_file = ('traindata.txt')
with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        next(my_input_file) # skip first row
        line = ['X:{} Y:{} Z:{}'.format(int(float(row[0])),int(float(row[1])), int(float(row[2])))  for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
        my_output_file.write("\n".join(line))
    my_output_file.close()
```

Input csv file,

```
-222.0, 34.0, 75.0
-222.0, 34.0, 75.0
-223.0, 41.0, 72.0
```

Output text file,

```
X:-222 Y:34 Z:75
X:-222 Y:34 Z:75
X:-223 Y:41 Z:72
```

Comment: X:-222.0, Y:34.0, Z:75.0, This is the outcome i get which is correct, but is there a way to change it into an integer instead of a float?

Comment: do you want to change all values to integer?

Comment: yea i wanna change all the values to interger

Comment: i got this error ,ValueError: could not convert string to float: , not sure why but in my csv file the data is integer and not float, but when it saves into txt it becomes float.  CSV Data =                                                                                         `x y z`
`-222  34 75`
`-222  34 75`

Comment: can you post the content of your csv including first line?

Comment: ive added the picture of what it looked like